# Less file keeps deleting data in CSS file when running file watchers on Mac

Tags: css, macos, intellij-idea, less

Every time I run file watchers on my primary less file, it deletes the CSS in the primary css file. This also occurs when I run it on sub-less files that feed into the primary css file. I am using intelliJ and currently have the following settings setup for the file watcher.

[File Watchers Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqYu5.png)

What could be the reason for it to be doing this?
And how could I fix it?

Comment: Hmm, are you expecting it to *append* the compiled CSS to the already exiting CSS stuff in that file? If so, no, this is not how it's supposed to work (compilers never append but always create a new file).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem with node - if you are running the current version (v6.0.0) it may be unstable enough to prevent less from compiling correctly. Bump your node version down to at least the LTS version (v4.4.3) and see if that solves your problem.

[This problem has been around for a while](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/238) but seems that it was solved by dropping your version back.